# How to do recursion?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

How transform one array to other with recursion? This example works only to second level.

```
$array2 = array();
foreach ($array as $levelKey => $level) {
  foreach ($level as $itemKey => $item) {
    if (isset($array[$levelKey + 1])) {
      $array2[$item['data']['id']] = $item;
      $children = $this->searchChildren($item['data']['id'], $array[$levelKey + 1]);
      $array += $children;
    }               
  }
}

function searchChildren($parent_id, $level)
{
  $_children = array();
  foreach ($level as $key => $item) {
    if ($item['data']['parent_id'] === $parent_id) {
      $_children[$key] = $item;
    }
  }
  return $_children;
}
```

Comment: You have to call your function within itself...

Comment: In order to understand recursion you have to understand recursion.

Comment: And when you show it on my example?

Comment: SO doesn't do your homework for you. Try to read about recursion, try to write a code, and come back with problems you might have.

Comment: what have you tried? Yes you have code, but what have you tried in terms of creating this recursion?

Comment: This post might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273733/how-to-do-recursion

Comment: @Eduard Luca I tried couple of hours. This advice is really useful, thank you.

Comment: @UnholyRanger I tried transform threedimensial array to twodimensial with preserving order

Comment: @tomasr Come back when you've tried for a couple of _days_! Hours is not a long time to spend working through a problem.

Comment: @WesleyMurch: I lol'd out loud.

Answer (score 0):

To move through a multidimensional array recursively use the **array_walk_recursive** function.

Docs can be found here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example of a use for recursion. This function *recursively* prints the concatenated keys and values of all items in the array

```
function printArrayWithKeys(array $input, $prefix = null) {
    foreach ($input as $key=>$value) {
        $concatenatedKey = $prefix . '.' . $key;
        if (is_array($value)) {
            printArrayWithKeys($value, $concatenatedKey);
        } else {
            print $concatenatedKey . ': ' . $value . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

The key to this function is that *it calls itself* when it encounters another array (thus continuing to traverse all levels of the array)

You can call it with input such as:

```
array(
    array(
        array( 'Hello', 'Goodbye' ),
        array( 'Again' )
    ),
    'And Again'
)
```

Where it would print:

```
0.0.0: Hello
0.0.1: Goodbye
0.1.0: Again
1: And Again
```